# Automapper - Mapping a Dictionary Field to a Class

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to map a Dictionary<string, object> property to a class. My entities and DTOs like below:

```
//Entities
public class Obj
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { set; get; }
}

//DTOs
public class ObjDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public MetadataDto MetadataInfo { get; set; }
}

public class MetadataDto
{
    public string Link { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I configured my mapping profile like below:

```
 public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Obj, ObjDto>().ForMember(dest => dest.MetadataInfo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Metadata));
            CreateMap<Metadata, MetadataDto>().ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "Name").Value));
            CreateMap<Metadata, MetadataDto>().ForMember(x => x.Link, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "Link").Value));
        }
    }
```

and this is how I tested the mapping results:

```
   public class Test
   {
      private readonly IMapper mapper;

      public Test(IMapper mapper)
      {
          this.mapper = mapper;
      }
      public void MappingTest()
      {
         var dataList = new List<Obj>
         {
            { new Obj{
                Id ="1" ,
                Metadata= new Metadata{
                    Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Name", "Test1" },{ "Link","Test Link 1"} } } }
            },
                { new Obj{
                Id ="2" ,
                Metadata= new Metadata{
                    Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Name", "Test2" },{ "Link", "Test Link 2" } } } }
            }
          }.AsQueryable();
          var result = this.mapper.Map<IList<ObjDto>>(dataList);
       }        
    }
```

but the results are not as I expected. "Name" fields are null for each list item. I think the last mapping configuration suppresses the others.

What is the correct mapping configuration for that scenario or how can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks for your reply, do you know how can I map if the dictionary has only lower letters for keys? My entities use pascal-case but all keys are lower-case in the dictionary. Is there any config or annotation for that?

Comment: That's not possible. But you can add an intermediary step with classes where that kind of thing can be configured.